# How obtain list of qooxdoo sublasses programmatically

Tags: qooxdoo

I am working on a ClojureScript wrapper for qx.mobile and would like to programmatically build a cljs type hierarchy mirroring the qx class hierarchy.

Is there a way to get all the subclasses of a qooxdoo class?

How about a programmatic way to query the superclass of a class?

I am already putting qx.Class.getProperties to good use.

Thx, kt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging arround a bit in qx.Class we decided to implement a method qx.Class.getSubclasses which returns a hash object with all subclasses of a given class.

```
var subclasses = qx.Class.getSubclasses(qx.ui.core.Widget);
```

gets all subclasses of qx.ui.core.Widget.

Landed in qooxdoo master with commit https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/pull/9037

Comment: Great. Checking it out now. Thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: Please report back if this works for you. And please use the github issue tracker at https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/issues for reporting bugs since the bugzilla tracker will be shut down soon.

Answer (score 4):

The programmatic way of getting the superclass of a given class is documented at http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.Class

```
<classname>.superclass
```

or getting the name of the superclass as a string

```
<classname>.superclass.classname
```

which means that e.g.

```
qx.ui.core.Widget.superclass.classname
```

will return the string "qx.ui.core.LayoutItem".

Regarding the programmatic way to retreive all subclasses of a class:
This is currently not possible without iterating the whole class hierarchy/tree and testing the objects against being subclasses of the given class.

We discussed at https://gitter.im/qooxdoo/qooxdoo that it maybe would be usefull to create an array for each class holding the subclasses. This could be added to the code of the private method __createClass in qx.Class.

We would like to encourage everyone who needs this (or other) functionalities to join us on https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/ and help extending qooxdoo by creating a pull requests. Thank you.